# How to integrate alexa with web application?

Tags: web, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have a simple angular application which needs to be integrated with Alexa. I spend many hours on this but still did not get a solution. The question is, is it possible to use Alexa without an echo device in web?If yes, how?

Currently I am not worried about the alexa skills. I just want alexa to talk.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want speech synthesis, it's supported by most browsers using the Web Speech API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API#speech_synthesis

Since it's supported by Chrome, it may be supported by Chromium-based browsers like Edge and Opera. Haven't tried.

If you specifically want Alexa's voice, IIRC that's unique to the Alexa domain.

If you want another wider selection of voice synthesis options, there's Amazon Polly: https://aws.amazon.com/polly/